# Using Jquery's .closest to access audio element not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I used `.each()` and `before()` to automatically insert an audio element with class `'pipe1'` for a hover effect before every element of class `'product_name'` because an individual audio element cannot overlap itself, thus each button needs its own sound effect.

I know the insert worked, because when I inspect the page I see the element.  The element played when being accessed directly, but now using `.closest()` it isn't working.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

The following is the HTML generated, which I found with Firefox's 'inspect element':

```
<audio class="pipe1">
  <source src="/frontshift/audio/pipe1.mp3"></source>
  <source src="/frontshift/audio/pipe1.ogg"></source>
</audio>
<span class="product_name">Product</span>
```

All of the code I'm working with is activated in the same .hover effect, which is `$(".product_name").hover()`

The following code successfully plays the audio:

```
$(".pipe1")[0].currentTime = .04;
$(".pipe1")[0].play();
```

The following code does NOT:

```
$(this).closest(".pipe1").currentTime = .04;
$(this).closest(".pipe1").play();
```

The following alert turns up undefined:

```
alert($(this).closest(".pipe1").attr("class"));
```

Comment: If your code is in a handler attached to the `.product_name` element, then how would `.closest()` be able to find the `<audio>`? They're siblings according to your HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.closest()` selects ancestors, to select previous sibling use `.prev()`

```
var audio = $(this).prev(".pipe1")[0];
audio.currentTime = .04;
audio.play();
```

Comment: You didn't actually edit it, you just SUGGESTED an edit.  It still has to be approved before it goes into effect.  And THANK YOU Musa, I feel like a dummy.

Comment: By the way, could you tell me why the [0] is necessary, since it should just select one element anyway?

Comment: @Mr.Lavalamp: NULL edited the post accidentally. Higher rep users don't need approvals for their edits. You can see the revision history by clicking the `edited` link.

Comment: @Mr.Lavalamp `play` and `currentTime` are properties of the audio element and to access the audio element from the jQuery object you use the `[]` notation or `.get()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the DOM node from the jQueryObject:

```
$(this).closest(".pipe1").get(0).currentTime = 0.4
```

Or using Array like behavior:

```
$(this).closest(".pipe1")[0].currentTime = 0.4
```

Are you sure that the context (`this`) refers to an element inside the audio tag?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you should use `$(this).prev('.pipe1');`

Comment: Should be a comment dont'cha think?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to reply to @am not i am but I didn't find how to.

Comment: His reputation is too low to comment on anything but his own posts.